# Process builder triggered by API is not sending email upon task creation

Tags: soap-api, process-builder

I have a process in the process builder which creates tasks when the status of a specific object is changed. When I change the status manually the process will fire as expected and a bunch of tasks are created and the corresponding emails are sent.
 However if I change the status using the SOAP API the emails are not sent, but the tasks are created.

Both of the scenarios are run with the same credentials in the same environment and I am including the email header in the API call.

Is this a bug with a potential workaround or is there some setting that I might have missed?